# Iterate through variables in Robot Framework Click Element

Tags: robotframework

As part of a Robot Framework test I would like to access multiple objects from my page with the same keyword. The xpath of the objects looks like this:

```
//div[@class='col-sm-4 ng-scope']//h1[@class='ng-binding'][contains(text(),'Bot1')]
//div[@class='col-sm-4 ng-scope']//h1[@class='ng-binding'][contains(text(),'Bot2')]
//div[@class='col-sm-4 ng-scope']//h1[@class='ng-binding'][contains(text(),'Botx')]
```

I've tried to set a list variable with the name of my test objects (elements)

```
*** Variables ***
@{TESTBOTS} =  Bot1  Bot2  Botx

*** Keywords ***
Delete Bots
    go to  ${LANDINGURL}
    Sleep  3s
    Click Element  //div[@class='col-sm-4 ng-scope']//h1[@class='ng-binding'][contains(text(), @{TESTBOTS})]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
FAIL        Element with locator '//div[@class='col-sm-2 ng-scope']//h1[@class='ng-binding'][contains(text(),'${TESTBOTS')]' not found.
```

I'd really appreciate if you could point me to the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be missing a keyword on the last line of `Delete Bots` -- you just have an xpath where a keyword should be.

Comment: Thank Bryan! You are right. The uploaded snippet was incorrect. Here is the actual code I've tried:                                    *** Variables ***
@{TESTBOTS} =  Bot1  Bot2  Botx

*** Keywords ***
Delete Bots
    go to  ${LANDINGURL}
    Sleep  3s
    Click Element  //div[@class='col-sm-4 ng-scope']//h1[@class='ng-binding'][contains(text(), @{TESTBOTS})]

Answer (score 3):

The error message still does not seem to fit the snippet, I believe.

But anyway: with `@{TESTBOTS}` you unwrap the complete list. I would have expect an error like *No element found with text 'Bot1  Bot2  Botx'*

I think this should work iterating the list of testbots:

```
FOR    ${testbot}    IN    @{TESTBOTS}
    Click Element    //div[@class='col-sm-4 ng-scope']//h1[@class='ng-binding'][contains(text(), ${testbot})] 
END
```

Comment: Thanks so much Noordsestern! Exactly what I was looking for!